# Does disable log error for MySQL increasing it's performance ? How disable it?

Tags: mysql, logging

Does disabling error logging for MySQL increase its performance? How can I disable it?

Here is my server's load:

```
Server load     0.63 (8 CPUs)   
Memory Used     23.38% (957,600 of 4,096,000)   
Swap Used       0% (0 of 1)
```

And here is a screenshot of the `process manager`
http://elnhrda.com/promgr.jpg

The contents of `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=64M
skip-name-resolve
#innodb_file_per_table=1
query_cache_limit=2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 8M
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
```

I am looking for any suggestion that could increase my website's speed.

I have VPS, 4GB RAM, CENTOS 6, X86_64.

**Please note:** these statistics were calculated now with no queries executed, and the site had no visitors in the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Error logging should not have significant impact on your MySQL performance, as there shouldn't be many of them. If you've got enough errors for logging to impact performance, the solution is to fix the errors, not ignore them.

You have relatively low CPU load and low memory usage. Do some benchmarking to find out what's making your site slow instead of selecting possible optimizations at random.

Comment: Does 23.38% is low when no any visitors or any operations on the databse?

Comment: MySQL will attempt to load as much into cache as it can, in order to speed up queries. A MySQL database with zero queries **should** still be taking up a lot of RAM if it's properly configured.

Comment: Well, Could you please suggest any ideas to improve MySQL performance?

Comment: Have you benchmarked it to confirm that MySQL performance *is* your problem? Have you done `EXPLAIN` queries to evaluate your queries? Do you have MySQL's slow query log enabled to find which ones to optimize?

Comment: i think i don't have any slow queries, the problem is when the site publish posts MySQL slowdown it because i have a lot of daily posts about 3K dialy

Comment: That's one insertion every 30 seconds or so - hardly significant load if it's coded well. You're going to have to do some digging. Don't "think", **know**. Enabling the slow query log is easy and very useful.

Comment: My website is using RSS aggregation feature with auto publish it via cronjob